# Высчитывание чисел способом рандом

Tags: php

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET id =`id`+ 2 + ROUND(RAND() * 3) where username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Как высчитать, на какие числа замениться id, прошу скинуть алгоритм высчитывания, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = $id + 2 + rand(0,3);
```

Answer (score 2):

Похоже что двумя запросами:

```
SELECT id FROM `users` WHERE username = '{$_SESSION["username"]}' FOR UPDATE
// вытаскиваем $id
// что-то делаем с id типа:
// $id += 2 + rand(0,3);
UPDATE `users` SET id = {$id} WHERE username = '{$_SESSION["username"]}'
```

Тогда со времени select-а до update строка залочится

Comment: и вам спасибо =)

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя высчитать.